# I have to replicate the scenario where i need my POD to be paused or stop

Tags: kubernetes

Command to pause or stop POD , I have to replicate scenario in production
POD contains containers running 
there is a way to pause docker containers is there any way for POD in Kubernetes

Comment: your question is very hard to understand. can you please explain again?

Comment: 1: There are multiple POD in cluster
2: One of the POD want to shut down or want to make down
3: But there is already a setting once any POD down one more instance again comes UP

Is there anyway to make this happen using kubectl command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your request correctly you should just scale up/down your deployment:

```
kubectl scale deployment <deployment_name> --replicas=<number_of_needed_pods>
```